invoke a `@classmethod`-annotated method
Dummy scenario:
# where I want to collect my decorated callbacks
cbs = []

# decorator to mark a callback to be collected
def my_deco(cb):
    cbs.append(cb)
    return cb

class C:
    @my_deco
    @classmethod
    def cm(cls):
        ...

# execute the collected callbacks
for cb in cbs:
    cb()

my goal is to have a my_deco decorator that collect some callbacks and execute them at a given time
I can apply my_deco to normal functions and they are collected and invoked normally. I also may call my_deco(C.cm) after C definition and the collected method is invoke-able normally.
In the example - however - I want to apply my_deco inside the definition of the class C.
I am struggling to understand how to detect

that I'm decorating a classmethod object (atm I'm checking if isinstance(cb, classmethod) but I'm not sure is correct
how to retrieve the C class itself: assuming it's a classmethod instance my understanding is that is an "unbounded" method, such as the invocation require to manually set the cls parameter. But I don't know how to retrieve C in the my_deco implementation


A classmethod is only visible as a callable (a "bound classmethod"), when it is retrieved from the class itself, with either the . notation, or with getattr. When you use the decorator in the class body, it will "see" a classmethod instance, which is an object with a custom __get__ method which will retrieve the function, and fill in the cls argument at call time.
The problem with your approach is that at call time you don´t want to refence the class, just use it as a namespace: just a callable, without parameters: at classmethod definition time, that information is not available: it is filled up only when one retrieves a classmethod from an already created class.
Bear with me:

class C:
    @my_deco
    @classmethod
    def c_cm(cls):
        print(f"Call `c_cm()` on class `{cls.__name__}`")
      
class D(C):
    pass
    

Now, when the callbacks are executed, should C.c_cm OR D.c_cm be called? Each should get the class as first parameter and potentially behave differently. (Otherwise, you could use staticmethod instead of classmethod and your decorator will just work in Python 3.11 + (and with some changes, also in older Python´s, there is a relativelly recent change to staticmethod behavior).
Otherwise, the thing to do is just do not use the decorator syntax, and call my_deco after  the class body is defined. In other words, this:

class C:
    @classmethod
    def c_cm(cls):
        print(f"Call `c_cm()` on class `{cls.__name__}`")
        
mydeco(C.c_cm)

And there you go: C.c_cm will unanbiguously be called, and this approach will also work for your nested classes examples.
Either that or using @staticmethod instead of classmethod will work. What you want  would be incorrect anyway, since in case of inheritance you will be calling the classmethod with incorrect parameters. If you want that, them, introspecting the module and qualname attributes are the only way to go anyway:
(semantically incorrect - please avoid production use)

import sys
# where I want to collect my decorated callbacks
cbs = []

# decorator to mark a callback to be collected
def my_deco(cb):
    original = cb
    if isinstance(cb, classmethod):
        # avoid side effects of rebinding "cb" in the closure
        func = cb
        def cb(*args, **kw):
            container = sys.modules[func.__module__]
            for component in func.__qualname__.split("."):
                container = getattr(container, component)
            return container(*args, **kw)
    cbs.append(cb)
    return original

class C:
    class D:
        @my_deco
        @classmethod
        def cm(fg):
            print("called")

# execute the collected callbacks
for cb in cbs:
    cb()

So, this last example should work exactly as you asking for - but besides the semantic problem when there is inheritance involved, there are edge cases with factory-defined classes, name-rebinding, module name (if it is in the main module and you are using multiprocessing, for example), and maybe a few others, due to the string based attribute retrieval approach.
The recommended, much simpler and production-reliable approach, is to just call my_deco after the class body is defined, without the decorator syntax.

i came up with the following solution, but it doesn't directly decorate the wanted method(s), but preselects them in a _fields class-variable. For sure you could extend this solution with decorator, which injects the wanted names in _fields, but I would re-think my design if I was you:
# where I want to collect my decorated callbacks
cbs = []


def extract(cls_obj):
    #_fields must be defined in the class
    fields = getattr(cls_obj, "_fields", None)
    for field in fields:
        _func_obj = vars(cls_obj)[field]
        _call = _func_obj.__get__(_func_obj)
        cbs.append(_call)


class SelectMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, clsdict):
        clsobj = super().__new__(cls, name, bases, clsdict)
        
        extract(clsobj) # <-- method(s) extraction 
        return clsobj


class C(metaclass=SelectMeta):
    _fields = ["cm1", "cm2"]
    @classmethod
    def cm1(cls):
        print("C.cm1")

    @classmethod
    def cm2(cls):
        print("C.cm2")


class B(metaclass=SelectMeta):
    _fields = ["cm1", "cm2"]
    @classmethod
    def cm1(cls):
        print("B.cm1")

    @classmethod
    def cm2(cls):
        print("B.cm2")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for cb in cbs:
        cb()

>>> C.cm1
>>> C.cm2
>>> B.cm1
>>> B.cm2


This error message occurs because you are trying to call a "classmethod" as if it was a regular method, it is however an object of type "classmethod".
To circumvent that you can use the __get__ dunder method of your classmethod object cb to get a callable object like this:
for cb in cbs:
    cb.__get__(C)()


This assumes every callable added to cbs requires C (or a subclass thereof) as its first argument.

It has also problem with the arguments (args or kwargs) if provided.

@baskettaz for the args/kwargs keep in mind that this is a simplified example, and assume that I want to decorate only callbacks without parameters / classmethods with cls etc...

@mark - as cbepner said I know I can pass the class object, but my issue is that I don't know how to retrieve it
